# How do I pass the value of the rows from the crud table to the custom submit button

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, checkbox, datatables, laravel-backpack

This is the tab i have implemented and fetched the datas from an another crud controller

[image]

I have tried using bulk action to select the row and pass the value of the row to the custom button 
But i couldnt

I have also tried by using j query as well but it didnt worked well

```
 $(document).ready(function (){   


    //    var table = $('#crudtable').DataTable({
    //       'data': userData,  
    //       'columnDefs': [{
    //          'targets': 0,
    //          'searchable':false,
    //          'orderable':false,
    //          'className': 'dt-body-center',


    //    });


    //    $('.crud_bulk_actions_row_checkbox').on('click', function(){
    //       // Check/uncheck all checkboxes in the table
    //       var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
    //       $('.crud_bulk_actions_row_checkbox', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
    //    });


    //    $('#crudtable tbody').on('change', ''.crud_bulk_actions_row_checkbox', function(){
    //       // If checkbox is not checked
    //       if(!this.checked){
    //          var el = $('#example-select-all').get(0);

    //          if(el && el.checked && ('indeterminate' in el)){

    //             el.indeterminate = true;
    //          }
    //       }
    //    });

    //    $('#crudtable').on('#button3', function(e){
    //       var form = this;

    //       // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
    //       table.$('.crud_bulk_actions_row_checkbox').each(function(){
    //          // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
    //          if(!$.contains(document, this)){
    //             // If checkbox is checked
    //             if(this.checked){
    //                // Create a hidden element 
    //                $(form).append(
    //                   $('<input>')

    //                      .attr('name', this.name)
    //                      .val(this.value)
    //                );
    //             }
    //          } 
    //       });



    // });
    // ";
```

Comment: Can you share the controller class? and explain what you want to do clearly please?

Answer (score 1):

To learn how custom buttons work in Backpack, take a look at the [button docs](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-buttons#creating-a-custom-button).

If you're creating a bulk button (where you can select multiple rows and do an action on all of them) I recommend you start your button from the ["bulk clone" button code](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/resources/views/crud/buttons/bulk_clone.blade.php) - it's a great example of a simple bulk button, just a confirmation dialog and an AJAX call.

Your custom button must follow the structure of Backpack bulk buttons:

```php
    @if ($crud->hasAccess('bulkClone') && $crud->get('list.bulkActions'))
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="bulkCloneEntries(this)" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary bulk-button"><i class="fa fa-clone"></i> Clone</a>
    @endif

    @push('after_scripts')
    <script>
        if (typeof bulkCloneEntries != 'function') {
          function bulkCloneEntries(button) {
              if (typeof crud.checkedItems === 'undefined' || crud.checkedItems.length == 0)
              { alert('No items selected'); return; }

              // your logic here
          }
    </script>
    @endpush
```

Notice:

- the button calls a custom function `onClick`;
- that function is pushed in the "after_scripts" blade section;

Comment: Thanku so much @tabacitu